# Getting started with Netbean Platform?

Tags: java, netbeans, netbeans-platform

I wanted to build Java Application using netbean platform but there were no any NetBeans platform to select from.And I could not add one using **Manage** button.How do I get started?
I am using **Netbean 7.0**
[image: Error]

[image: Error2]

Comment: what version of NetBeans are you using ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm unsure as to why your installation has become corrupted in this way but you can always add a Platform to your installation through `Tools > NetBeans Platform` menu item. Click the `Add Platform...` button and browse to your NetBeans' install directory, for example:

> C:\Users\Me\Program Files (x86)\NetBeans 7.0

Then you should be able to select the platform in the wizard.

---

You should only need to select the **top level directory** for this to work. I've included a screenshot for you to compare yours to. It's possible that your installation of NetBeans has become corrupted and if you are not seeing the same behavior as pictured below then most likely you'll need to reinstall NetBeans.
Notice in the below screenshot that the `Platform Name:` is filled out (top red arrow) and the `Next` button is enabled.

[image: Screenshot of NetBeans Platform Manager]

Comment: I tried this but could not find any module :( ! I have added the snap shot!

Comment: I've added some more info to my answer.

Comment: After looking more closely at the second screenshot you added I realized that you are selecting the wrong directory. The one you want to select is the NetBeans **install** directory and not the settings directory that you've selected